# how many set of characters can be generated

Tags: php, math

i am creating a list of words at length of 10 characters.. with the character combination of 78 letters(a-z,A-Z,0-9 & special chars).
i **want to generate each and every word** that can be made with this condition.
i am doing this in PHP..
want to know the how much words would i get?

```
for($i=0;$i<=608400;$i++) {
                    $special_char=array("'","/","@,","#","$","%","(",")",",","?","[","]","+","=","!","*");
                    $original_string = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a','z'), range('A', 'Z'),$special_char);
                    $original_string = implode("", $original_string);
                   $char[]=substr(str_shuffle($original_string), 0, $length);
                }
```

for example: Character length is 2 and the character combination is "a" and "b".
i would get words "ab" and "ba". so total number is 2.

Comment: 78^10 = 8335775831236199424. It's going to take a while.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math/combinatorics, not about programming. It is better asked at http://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Btw: What about "aa" and "bb" in your example? That makes a total number of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**4566176969818464000**

From this site: http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html

Types to choose from? 78

Number Chosen? 10

Is Order important? Yes

Is Repetition allowed? No

Short Answer: 4.56617696e+18

**Full Answer: 4566176969818464000**

Comment: Your answer is wrong because you did NOT calculate the passwords, that they are less than 78 characters length.

Comment: All allowed words are less than 78 chars length: they must be exactly 10 characters long, as requested!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit unclear from the original form of your question if same characters are allowed or not (the description suggests they are, but the example suggests they are not).

If they are allowed, than any character of the 78 can be the first character of the word. The second character can be chosen again from the total 78-character alphabet, independently from the first one: 78 possibilities again. And so on, 78 possibilities at each character, we can choose independently, so these can be simply multiplied, giving the final answer of 78^10.

If repetitions are not allowed, the answer is slightly different. Still we can choose any of the 78 characters to be the first character of the word. But no matter which character we chose, there are only 77 possible second characters, as we cannot repeat the first one. The third one should not match any of the former two, leaving us with 76 possibilities, and so on. Thus the answer in this case is 78*77*76*75*74*73*72*71*70*69=78!/(78-10)!.